# Get text from javascript json array

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON and I want to get the name 'Ethan Richardson' from the array photographer_name into a variable.

I have tried to use regex but I could not get that to work.

So what I want is to be left with a variable like   let name = 'Ethan Richardson'

The JSON structure is below:

```js
{
    "eventName": "Hilton Hotel",
    "photographer_name": ["Ethan Richardson"],
    "image_url": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/a0/b8/b6/a0b8b6b2e9b077a8ac7791455f83a27b.jpg",
    "subtitle": "Enjoy the night",
    "result": "1"
}
```

Comment: If your json data is available in a variable called `data` doing  `data.photographer_name` should get you `Ethan Richardson`

Comment: `object.photographer_name[0]` <- choose index 0

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"eventName":"Hilton Hotel","photographer_name":["Ethan Richardson"],"image_url":"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/a0/b8/b6/a0b8b6b2e9b077a8ac7791455f83a27b.jpg","subtitle":"Enjoy the night","result":"1"}');
var variable = json.photographer_name[0];
```

Comment: Your `json` variable is a JavaScript object, not JSON.

Comment: @bfontaine My bad, fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
const jsonString = '{"eventName":"Hilton Hotel","photographer_name":["Ethan Richardson"],"image_url":"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/a0/b8/b6/a0b8b6b2e9b077a8ac7791455f83a27b.jpg","subtitle":"Enjoy the night","result":"1"}'
const jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString)
const name = jsonObject.photographer_name[0]
```

Please never try to come up with custom parsing solutions, if tested and working ones exists

Comment: You shouldn't use JSON.parse without an `try ... catch`

Comment: And what should I do in catch? Not related to the question.

Comment: handle the error or rethrow it to handle it on top level

Comment: Don't want to argue about it, but it's way out of the scope of the question how parsing errors are handled.

Comment: Sure but if he should use Json.parse, he should know about it ;)

Comment: @BalázsÉdes simple solution. Add the relevant documentation for the OP to read about `JSON.parse()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse Adding the relevant references is always a bonus for anyone who might stumble on this quesiton seeking help and is new to any of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it first with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

> The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

and then take `photographer_name` as key.

```js
var json = '{"eventName":"Hilton Hotel","photographer_name":["Ethan Richardson"],"image_url":"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/a0/b8/b6/a0b8b6b2e9b077a8ac7791455f83a27b.jpg","subtitle":"Enjoy the night","result":"1"}',
    object = JSON.parse(json),
    name = object.photographer_name;

console.log(name);
```